# How to dynamically create multiple selectboxes for category tree

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have multiple categories with a sub-category-level limited to 6 subcategories. What I want is cascading selectboxes with the content of the parent category. Have a look at my screenshot:

[image]

On the left half-side we have strings of the customers-category (in this expl. it matches the selectable categories, but this is not always the case). The user should select a matching category from the apps category-tree.
When the user selects the main category, another selectbox appears with the contents of main category - and so on....

My current problem is that always all selectboxes of a level are set with the selected value, but they should be independant. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<form *ngIf="!!customerCategories" (ngSubmit)="onCategorizeSubmit(mapForm.value)" #mapForm="ngForm">
        <div *ngFor="let customerCategory of customerCategories" class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-label" class="col-form-label">{{ customerCategory }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <select *ngIf="!!selectLevel0Visible" class="form-select" class="col" name="{{ customerCategory }}_0"
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedCategoryLevel0" (change)="onSelectLevel0($event.target)">
                    <option>Bitte auswählen...</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let googleCategoryLevel0 of googleCategoriesLevel0"
                        value="{{googleCategoryLevel0.id}}">
                        {{ googleCategoryLevel0.pathFragment }}</option>
                </select>
                
                [...]
                
                <select *ngIf="!!selectLevel6Visible" class="form-select" class="col" name="{{ customerCategory }}_6"
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedCategoryLevel6">
                    <option>Bitte auswählen...</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let googleCategoryLevel6 of googleCategoriesLevel6"
                        value="{{googleCategoryLevel6.id}}">
                        {{ googleCategoryLevel6.pathFragment }}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-start" (click)="cancelAssistant()">Assistent
            abbrechen</button>
            <button *ngIf="!currentFeed.isCategorized" type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-end" type="submit">Kategorisieren</button>
            <button *ngIf="!!currentFeed.isCategorized" type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-end" matStepperNext>Weiter</button>
    </form>
```

TS:

```
export class CategorizeFeedComponentFeature implements OnChanges {

  @Input() currentFeed: FeedmapConfigDto;
  customerCategories: string[];
  googleCategoriesLevel0: GCategoryDto[];
  [...]
  googleCategoriesLevel6: GCategoryDto[];

  selectedCategoryLevel0: number;
  [...]
  selectedCategoryLevel6: number;

  selectLevel0Visible: boolean = true;
  [...]
  selectLevel6Visible: boolean = false;

  async ngOnChanges(): Promise<void> {
    if (!!this.currentFeed?.isImported) {
      this.customerCategories = await this.productService.getAllCustomerCategoriesByFeedmapConfigId(this.currentFeed.id).toPromise();
      this.googleCategoriesLevel0 = await this.categoryService.getAllGoogleCategories(0).toPromise();
    }
  }

  async onSelectLevel0(eventTarget: EventTarget): Promise<void> {
    const value = +(eventTarget as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.googleCategoriesLevel1 = await this.categoryService.getAllGoogleCategories(value).toPromise();
    if (this.googleCategoriesLevel1.length > 0) {
      this.selectLevel1Visible = true;
    }
  }

  [...]

  async onSelectLevel5(eventTarget: EventTarget): Promise<void> {
    const value = +(eventTarget as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.googleCategoriesLevel6 = await this.categoryService.getAllGoogleCategories(value).toPromise();
    if (this.googleCategoriesLevel6.length > 0) {
      this.selectLevel6Visible = true;
    }
  }

  async onSelectLevel6(eventTarget: EventTarget): Promise<void> {
    const value = +(eventTarget as HTMLInputElement).value;
    // this.googleCategoriesLevel7 = await this.categoryService.getAllGoogleCategories(value).toPromise();
  }
}
```

Next to my question, I think there should be a better way to solve this - I´m thinking about a material tree with selectboxes. What is your opinion?

Regards

Comment: Your screenshot is broken.